# Implementing memory allocation and deallocation

Tags: c

I would like to write code in C that allocates data using a linked list and pointers without using `malloc`.

But I'm not sure how to implement it, so I'd like some help.

1. The initial allocated memory is 1MB.
2. Allocate memory equal to the size of the node and return its starting address.
3. If you check the memory window, the data entered by the user and the value of the next member of the node structure start from 1 and increase by 1.

Example) 00000001 00000001 / 00000002 00000002

When implementing the `myfree` function, implement a way to reuse deleted nodes instead of freeing memory.

If there is a good way, I would appreciate it if you could let me know. Because we use a translator, the sentences may be awkward. And although it's embarrassing, I'd like to share the code.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MEMORY_SIZE (1024 * 1024) // 1MB

// Definition of the linked list node structure
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

// Definition of the linked list structure
typedef struct {
    Node* head;
} LinkedList;

// Definition of the memory block structure
typedef struct MemoryBlock {
    void* address;
    size_t size;
    struct MemoryBlock* next;
} MemoryBlock;

int memory_block[MEMORY_SIZE]; // Total memory capacity
int* memory_ptr = memory_block; // Pointer to the end of the current memory block

MemoryBlock* free_memory = NULL; // List of free memory blocks

// Function to display memory status
void memoryStatus() {
    printf("\nUsed memory: %ld\n", (size_t)(memory_ptr - memory_block));
    printf("Remaining memory: %ld\n", (size_t)(MEMORY_SIZE - (memory_ptr - memory_block)));
}

// Memory allocation function
void* mymalloc(size_t size) {
    if (free_memory != NULL && free_memory->size >= size) {
        void* ptr = free_memory->address;
        free_memory = free_memory->next;
        return ptr;
    }
    else if ((size_t)(memory_ptr - memory_block) + size <= MEMORY_SIZE) {
        void* ptr = (void*)memory_ptr;
        memory_ptr += size;
        return ptr;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

// Memory deallocation function
void myfree(void* ptr, size_t size) {
    MemoryBlock* block = (MemoryBlock*)mymalloc(sizeof(MemoryBlock));
    if (block != NULL) {
        block->address = ptr;
        block->size = size;
        block->next = free_memory;
        free_memory = block;
    }
}

// Function to initialize the linked list
void initLinkedList(LinkedList* list) {
    list->head = NULL;
}

// Function to create a new node
Node* createNode(int data) {
    Node* newNode = (Node*)mymalloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newNode != NULL) {
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }
    return newNode;
}

// Function to append a node to the linked list
void appendNode(LinkedList* list, int data) {
    Node* newNode = createNode(data);
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
        return;
    }
    if (list->head == NULL) {
        list->head = newNode;
    }
    else {
        Node* current = list->head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}

// Function to delete a node from the linked list
void deleteNode(LinkedList* list, int data) {
    Node* current = list->head;
    Node* prev = NULL;

    while (current != NULL && current->data != data) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if (current == NULL) {
        printf("Data not found.\n");
        return;
    }

    if (prev == NULL) {
        // Delete the first node
        list->head = current->next;
    }
    else {
        prev->next = current->next;
    }

    myfree(current, sizeof(Node)); // Free node memory
}

// Function to print the linked list
void printList(LinkedList* list) {
    Node* current = list->head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    LinkedList linkedList;
    int data;

    initLinkedList(&linkedList); // Initialize the linked list

    do {
        printf("\n\n1. Add data to the linked list\n");
        printf("2. Delete data from the linked list\n");
        printf("3. Print the current linked list\n");
        printf("0. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);

        switch (data) {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter data to add to the linked list: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            appendNode(&linkedList, data);
            printf("Current linked list: ");
            printList(&linkedList);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter data to delete: ");
            scanf("%d", &data);
            deleteNode(&linkedList, data);
            printf("Current linked list: ");
            printList(&linkedList);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Current linked list: ");
            printList(&linkedList);
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice! Please try again.\n");
            break;
        }
        memoryStatus();
    } while (data != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current code? Does it not work? Does it fail to meet the requirements?

Comment: Is the requirement to implement a linked list using a Memory pool instead of malloc.  Or is it to implement a malloc-like Memory pool and you have decided to do that using Linked-lists?

Comment: Pedantic: When `int` is 16-bit, `1024*1204` overflows - may be zero.  Better as `#define MEMORY_SIZE 1048576u`.

Comment: Instead of freeing the memory you can put it in a linked list of available nodes. When you need a node, you get onne from the linked list (if any) or from the array (if any) or reallocate the array. If you use index values to link the lists instead of pointers, the setup will survive reallocation. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367779/4142924)

Comment: @Syntactics 
I'm implementing a memory pool like malloc, and I decided to implement it using Linked-list. There are nodes in a linked list, and I was thinking of reusing the nodes to implement myfree 

Comment: `int memory_block[MEMORY_SIZE]` vs. "The initial allocated memory is 1MB". Unless you are on a platform with very small `int`s, you have allocated `sizeof(int)` (usually 4) times more than you should have. Your pool should be a `char[]` instead.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for sharing great information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation will simply not work, conceptually.

You are allocating a chunk of `int` rather than bytes, which is strange. Then you wildly cast their addresses to structs etc. That's plain undefined behavior, there's no guarantees that structs share the same alignment and it's also a "strict aliasing violation", a bug caused by using the wrong pointer types.

You wouldn't be able to salvage this with an array of bytes like `uint8_t` etc either, because you can't wildly point straight into such an array either. This is a known problem when trying to implement `malloc` using standard C. Such implementations would rather have to depend on non-standard extensions such as gcc
`-fno-strict-aliasing`

A general advice for beginners is to *never* use casts. I count 6 casts in this program that are either blatantly incorrect or otherwise superfluous.

---

A classic fast implementation of linked lists is to use a fixed size node array:

- Rather than having `next` pointers, you have `next` indices as plain integers.
- You need some means to mark an item in the array as taken or free. Typically set the whole array to zero from start. Then have some flag per node to tell that it is allocated.
- Optionally you can keep track of the total used size.

This is simple and cache-friendly, unlike a naive linked list using individually allocated nodes on the heap (which should pretty much never be used in the real world). It can easily be converted to something like a priority queue or sorted container.

---